# Google Maps API - matching a request with the asynchronous response

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api, google-api-javascript-client

I'm using the google maps distance matrix javascript API to query the travel time from one point to about 50 destinations.
in order to do this, I need to break my query up into multiple chunks, since the google maps API allows only a maximum of 25 destinations per request.

the problem that I'm having is the synchronization of the request and the result.
other APIs offer the option to include a key that lets the developer match a request and an asynchronous result.
however, since such a parameter is missing from the request specification, I have no idea how to make sure that I'm matching the right data to my incoming results.

I would be glad for a "clean" workaround - currently the only idea that I'm having is to have a unique number of destinations for each request, for instance the first with 25, the next with 24 destinations and so on. but I would not consider this a satisfactory approach.
thank you

Comment: I answered similar question for Geocoding API. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47622937/5140781.

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for.